# How to get workspace path with Minecraft Coder Pack (MCP)?

Tags: java, file, minecraft

I'm making a Client with MCP and I need to get the data inside the path. I tried this code but it isn't working

```java
    File currDir = new File(".");
    String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(path);
    return (path + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "minecraft" + File.separator + "client" + File.separator + "data");
```

The path that I need is `<workspace_path>/src/minecraft/client/data`, however the code above returns `<workspace_path>/jars/src/minecraft/client/data`. I'm using IDE to run it so it is `jars` inside, however if I'm playing game, it will return the path to the Client Config path. 
Please help me, thanks!